# Force jQuery.load() to POST when using jQuery.param()

Tags: post, jquery, get, jquery-load

Ok, so `.load()` uses...

> The POST method is used if data is
>   provided as an object; otherwise, GET
>   is assumed.

I have the following...

```
// an array of itemIds
var items = $selected.map(function() {
   return $(this).find('.item').text();
}).get();

// post the data
$container.load(
    _url,
    $.param(data, true),
    function(response, status, xhr) {
        //...
    }
);
```

The problem I have is that if I use `$.param` to serialise the data, it seems that GET is used.

If I don't use `$.param` then POST is used but I run into the problem again with the array not being serialised correctly and I don't receive the data in my controller.

Is there an easy way around this?

Comment: Why not use `$.ajax`?  There's more work involved, but you get finer grained control over the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$.get(_url, $.param(data, true), function(data) {
  $container.html(data);
});
```

This will have the same effect as a call to *load* with parameters, but with a GET request instead of a POST request.

Comment: The op seems to asking to use POST method instead of GET